# Firestore create query taking long when collection having large data ~6K documents

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore and saving my data to various collections. But 1 of the collections is having appx 6.2k documents and it's taking about 2-5 minutes to execute the create query. While other collections which have fewer documents take less than 10 seconds.

I am using Firestore with JS. Have tried both .set and .add methods but it's taking time.

Using like:

```
firestore.collection("feeds").add({
    title: "Holiday Celeberation",
    country: "India"
})
.then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

Comment: Time will vary as per amount of data you are downloading and your internet speed. You can try paginating the data and fetch the documents in small groups

Comment: But in my case, I am not getting the data. I am saving the data and its taking time. Getting data has solution of pagination. But I am saving data and I have not indexed that collection even.

Comment: "it's taking about 2-5 minutes to execute the create query"  I thought it as a query then. What's your internet speed and how large are the documents? Also is your database located too far from you ?

Comment: It seems to be all fine with other things. I have DEV and PROD env. Both have different projects. Data on DEV env is less and create process is done quickly. On the other hand when I upload the Web App to PROD which has more than 6k documents then it starts taking time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firestore create query taking long when collection having large data ~6K documents

Everything in Firestore is about the number of documents that are returned by your queries. Since you say that you are trying to read ~6K documents, that's indeed the expected behavior.

The query performance in Firestore depends on the number of documents you request and not on the number of documents you search. It doesn't really matter if you search 10 documents in a collection of 1000 documents or in a collection that contains 100 MIL documents, the response time will always be the same. However, downloading an entire collection of ~6K documents is indeed a bad idea. Besides the fact that it takes so long, no one will ever be interested in such a large amount of data. I'm also very surprised how you didn't get an out-of-memory error.

So the solution that you have is to download that data in smaller chunks. This technique is called [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors). So you should always limit the data you get and try only to display data that can fit into the visible space.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thans for information. But that was not correct according to my question. 
I had said that the collection has ~6k documents but my question was not related to getting the data. My question is about creating new data in that collection. Creating new data in this collection is taking time. I've mentioned ~6k to let users consider if this may slow down the performace anyway. 
HENCE - Creating data in this collection is taking time rather than reading data from collection. I have used pagination for reading and that is working fine.

Comment: That was confusing "execute the create query". When you create a document is doesn't mean that you are creating a query. A query is created only when you read data. Besides that, the addition operation isn't affected in any way by the number of documents that exist in the collection. How do you measure that "taking time"? How do you know that it takes so long? What is the related code?

Comment: I am adding approx doc with 15 fields in a collection which is named as `feeds` and is having ~6k documents. When I create document in this collection. It takes approx 2-5 mins. But when I just change the collection name to some to some other name like `feedss` it gets added in very short time appx withing 2-4 seconds.

Comment: So you that `console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);` is triggered after 2-5 minutes when it comes to writing data in the collection with 6k documents, right?

Comment: Yes Right Alex.

Comment: If you try to write the same data in a collection that has, for example, 500 documents, what is the time? 2-5 minutes? Less than 10 seconds? 30 seconds?

Comment: It takes very less time. Appx 2 seconds, Can say less than 5 seconds.

Comment: As I understand it's not about the number of documents in the collection? Since writing a document in a collection of 500 documents takes the exact amount of time as writing in a collection with no documents, right?

Comment: Its negligible. I have not noticed this much. But I have replicated it and found when collection size going to be with more than 5k documents, Its starting taking time to save the data.

Comment: So everything works fine if the collection size is less than 5000 but takes a considerable long time when is greater than 5000, right?

Comment: Yes True. This is happening.

Comment: That's something else that's missing there. I personally tried that and it takes, less than a second.

Comment: Can it be something like cache which can cause this problem ? 
I tried same from iOS mobile app and it surprisingly taking about 1-2 seconds. But from my web app its taking much time. Anything other which can cause such issue ?  I can look at my end then.

Comment: It might. Have you tried to change the browser or to clean that cache? Do you get the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, Even tried on another systems and getting same problem.

BTW, If I am listening snapshots of 4 different collections which has approximately 10K docs and I am performing this operation on same page. Can that affect performance anyway?

Comment: Yes, since you listen for real-time updates from 4 collections with approximately 10K docs. That operation takes time so that's why you get that huge delay. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I meant that if its done so, then adding new data performance can vary ?
It  collections with approximately 10K docs and listening snapshots...

Comment: Yes indeed, it can vary. But remember how you structure your code. If your code waits for the read operation to complete and right after that to add the data, then that's definitely the reason why you encounter that behavior.

Comment: I am performing write operation after read is completed. Can caching from firebase slow down the speed of write operation as while writing snapshots will also be getting listened ?

Comment: If you perform the write operation after the read operation is complete, it explains now precisely why you have to wait for that much. **No**, caching cannot affect that. This is because you read the data from the cache **only when you are offline**. While online, you always read the online version of your documents. This means that you have to wait until you get all the data from the server :)

Comment: Hi Alex, Yet I am just looking at this problem. Actually I had read the collection 2 times in my web app, hence 12K documents are read and snapshots are listened. In such case writing takes time When I limit the read to like 1K - 3K, Its taking less time to write. Not sure yet what's the problem. Once I get it fixed from my end. I will update my answer with accpepting the answer so it can help others if they face same.

Comment: Even if you limit the results to 1K - 3K, that is still a lot of documents to read. Besides that, I don't think that someone will be ever interested in such a large amount of data. Ok, looking forward to seeing your update.

Comment: Output of thread - Thread was useful for getting clear to my issue. I am working for it refinement with pagination and listening less snapshots. @alex thanks for continuously being on it. Going to update as you said.